# The cardinality of an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In one of my assignments I'm given a set $A$ for which its cardinality is **not finite**, and a finite set $M = \{1,2,...,m\}$.

I'm asked to prove that the cardinality of $M\times A$ is equal to the cardinality of $A$.

I managed to find a surjective function from $M \times A$ to $A$, but I'm struggling with the other part of the proof (trying to use the "Squeeze theorem") given the fact that there is no further information on the set $A$.

Comment: What are you trying to say? This is the part that I did manage to prove, I'm struggling with the other side

Comment: oh sorry my bad.

Comment: The "Arithmetic" section here can help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number